# image opacity not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add opacity effect on the image. Its working only for the first image. This opacity effect is not working for the next images. I added jquery script also but its not working. Thanks in adance

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#imgDemo").css("opacity", 0.5);
    $("#imgDemo").hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 500);
    });
});
```

```css
body
{
    padding: 10px;
   
}
span
{
    font-family : Arial;
    font-size : 14pt;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row"> 
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <h2>Circle</h2>
  <p>The .rounded-circle class shapes the image to a circle:</p>            
  <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4p6k8mM7V7c/T6jolM6I_4I/AAAAAAAACL4/lTZyaeJyObM/s400/Change_Image_Opacity_Using_jQuery.jpg""  alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236" id="imgDemo"> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h2>Circle</h2>
  <p>The .rounded-circle class shapes the image to a circle:</p>            
  <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4p6k8mM7V7c/T6jolM6I_4I/AAAAAAAACL4/lTZyaeJyObM/s400/Change_Image_Opacity_Using_jQuery.jpg""  alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236" id="imgDemo"> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h2>Circle</h2>
  <p>The .rounded-circle class shapes the image to a circle:</p>            
  <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4p6k8mM7V7c/T6jolM6I_4I/AAAAAAAACL4/lTZyaeJyObM/s400/Change_Image_Opacity_Using_jQuery.jpg""  alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236" id="imgDemo"> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your id should be unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ids need to be unique. Alternatively, you can uses classes, by replacing `id` with `class`, and `#imgDemo` with `.imgDemo`, like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".imgDemo").css("opacity", 0.5);
    $(".imgDemo").hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 500);
    });
});
```

```css
body
{
    padding: 10px;
   
}
span
{
    font-family : Arial;
    font-size : 14pt;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row"> 
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <h2>Circle</h2>
  <p>The .rounded-circle class shapes the image to a circle:</p>            
  <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4p6k8mM7V7c/T6jolM6I_4I/AAAAAAAACL4/lTZyaeJyObM/s400/Change_Image_Opacity_Using_jQuery.jpg""  alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236" class="imgDemo"> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h2>Circle</h2>
  <p>The .rounded-circle class shapes the image to a circle:</p>            
  <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4p6k8mM7V7c/T6jolM6I_4I/AAAAAAAACL4/lTZyaeJyObM/s400/Change_Image_Opacity_Using_jQuery.jpg""  alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236" class="imgDemo"> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h2>Circle</h2>
  <p>The .rounded-circle class shapes the image to a circle:</p>            
  <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4p6k8mM7V7c/T6jolM6I_4I/AAAAAAAACL4/lTZyaeJyObM/s400/Change_Image_Opacity_Using_jQuery.jpg""  alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236" class="imgDemo"> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Its working. Thank you ery much

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your JS code is that your using the same `id` attribute repeated multiple times when they ***must*** be unique within the DOM.

*However* you don't need to use JS for this at all. It's more applicable in this case to use CSS, and it performs better than JS animation. To do it use the `:hover` selector and the `transition` rule. Try this:

```css
span {
  font: 14pt Arial;
  color: green;
}

.imgDemo {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.imgDemo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>Circle</h2>
      <p>The .rounded-circle class shapes the image to a circle:</p>
      <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4p6k8mM7V7c/T6jolM6I_4I/AAAAAAAACL4/lTZyaeJyObM/s400/Change_Image_Opacity_Using_jQuery.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236" class="imgDemo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 ">
      <h2>Circle</h2>
      <p>The .rounded-circle class shapes the image to a circle:</p>
      <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4p6k8mM7V7c/T6jolM6I_4I/AAAAAAAACL4/lTZyaeJyObM/s400/Change_Image_Opacity_Using_jQuery.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236" class="imgDemo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 ">
      <h2>Circle</h2>
      <p>The .rounded-circle class shapes the image to a circle:</p>
      <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4p6k8mM7V7c/T6jolM6I_4I/AAAAAAAACL4/lTZyaeJyObM/s400/Change_Image_Opacity_Using_jQuery.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236" class="imgDemo">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `id` you could use `class` property

**DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".imgDemo").css("opacity", 0.5);
    $(".imgDemo").hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 500);
    });
});
```

```css
body
{
    padding: 10px;
   
}
span
{
    font-family : Arial;
    font-size : 14pt;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row"> 
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <h2>Circle</h2>
  <p>The .rounded-circle class shapes the image to a circle:</p>            
  <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4p6k8mM7V7c/T6jolM6I_4I/AAAAAAAACL4/lTZyaeJyObM/s400/Change_Image_Opacity_Using_jQuery.jpg""  alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236" class="imgDemo"> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h2>Circle</h2>
  <p>The .rounded-circle class shapes the image to a circle:</p>            
  <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4p6k8mM7V7c/T6jolM6I_4I/AAAAAAAACL4/lTZyaeJyObM/s400/Change_Image_Opacity_Using_jQuery.jpg""  alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236" class="imgDemo"> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h2>Circle</h2>
  <p>The .rounded-circle class shapes the image to a circle:</p>            
  <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4p6k8mM7V7c/T6jolM6I_4I/AAAAAAAACL4/lTZyaeJyObM/s400/Change_Image_Opacity_Using_jQuery.jpg""  alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236" class="imgDemo"> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why **JS** ? Just use a class on all images and avoid using duplicate id's. ID should be unique

```css
body
{
    padding: 10px;
   
}
span
{
    font-family : Arial;
    font-size : 14pt;
    color: green;
}
.imgHover{
opacity:0.5;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease;
-ms-transition: all .5s ease;
-o-transition: all .5s ease;
transition: all .5s ease;
}

.imgHover:hover{
opacity:1;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row"> 
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <h2>Circle</h2>
  <p>The .rounded-circle class shapes the image to a circle:</p>            
  <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4p6k8mM7V7c/T6jolM6I_4I/AAAAAAAACL4/lTZyaeJyObM/s400/Change_Image_Opacity_Using_jQuery.jpg"  class="imgHover"  alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236" id="imgDemo"> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h2>Circle</h2>
  <p>The .rounded-circle class shapes the image to a circle:</p>            
  <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4p6k8mM7V7c/T6jolM6I_4I/AAAAAAAACL4/lTZyaeJyObM/s400/Change_Image_Opacity_Using_jQuery.jpg""  class="imgHover"  alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236" id="imgDemo"> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h2>Circle</h2>
  <p>The .rounded-circle class shapes the image to a circle:</p>            
  <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4p6k8mM7V7c/T6jolM6I_4I/AAAAAAAACL4/lTZyaeJyObM/s400/Change_Image_Opacity_Using_jQuery.jpg""  alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236" id="imgDemo" class="imgHover"> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```